# Are the lyrics of Yoko Kanno's "Moon" gibberish or intelligible?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, yoko-kanno, language

Are the lyrics of Yoko Kanno’s song [*Moon*](https://musicbrainz.org/work/f2f35022-c7ce-497a-9b5c-c204088d60e2) meaningless (as in using [pseudowords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoword), [gibberish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibberish), [scat singing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scat_singing) or similar), or are the lyrics in some kind of language?

Maybe a [fictional language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictional_language) constructed by Yoko Kanno (AKA Gabriela Robin), possibly also used in her other works that use similar lyrics? Or maybe puns/wordplays, as described as special case for Japanese music in [Word Salad Lyrics](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordSaladLyrics), "based on alternate translations of the kanji used" or "similar-sounding words"?

###What I've learned so far…

I found many claims that it’s not in any kind of language, but none of them are from authoritative sources, and none of them cover the possibilities that it could be a fictional language or Japanese wordplays.

- Xah Lee claims on his [page about *Moon*](http://xahmusic.org/music/Turn_A_Gundam-Moon_song.html):

> As with many of Yoko Kanno's songs, the lyrics is meaningless vocalizations, not of any language.

- From [Gabriela Robin’s article](http://yokokanno.wikia.com/wiki/Gabriela_Robin) in a wiki about Yoko Kanno:

> Her very characteristic is to often write lyrics in a specific language she seems to be the only one capable of translate.

- From [Yoko Kanno’s article](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Music/YokoKanno) in TV Tropes (but not in particular about *Moon*):

> [Word Salad Lyrics](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordSaladLyrics): When she writes lyrics, this can happen. And sometimes what sounds like word salad is actually a nonsense language.

- In the thread [What language is this song?](http://loadingreadyrun.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=11700) in the LoadingReadyRun forum, various languages are suggested, and some claim that it’s just gibberish. A source (supposedly a fan page, which I can’t locate) is quoted:

> Her non-sensical lyrics have been known to drive the unknowing fan searching for translations from different linguists, but to no avail.

Comment: Regarding the (as of now) 2 close votes: It would be helpful to explain *why* this question is considered to be "unclear" or "primarily opinion-based". *Opinion* is not involved at all, and I have no idea how to phrase the question (it’s the last paragraph) more *clear*.

Comment: The word "meaningful" probably does not convey the meaning you intend (i.e. is this an actual language, or just a vocal improvisation with wordless vocables like scat... if that is what you are asking). Asking if a song is *meaningful* (incorrectly) sounds like you are asking if the song is significant or expressive with some value...  which isn't really a good debate for this type of Q&A. I would suggest getting to the crux of your question without the excessive setup and quotes leading into it.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Thanks! That is exactly what I want to ask, and I was not aware that it might not convey it. I tried to rephrase it. Would this work better? (I’m a non-native speaker and just looked up the term "gibberish" -- I’ve not enough feeling for the language to decide if it’s appropriate in this case)

Comment: unor, I made a few minor corrections, but I think it works now. It sounds completely "answerable" now. Thank you for the clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lyrics itself are meaningless, but the language does have a name - it's called *Gablish* and was indeed invented by Yoko Kanno.

She wrote several songs, that express a similar style, under the pseudonym Gabriela Robin. Mostly they sound like a language you may know, but than again they don't mean anything - at least not to the listener. I would dare to speculate this is also a bit related to the Japanese pronunciation of certain letters - specifically "R", which they can't pronounce that easily and makes foreign languages sound badly distorted.

You may enjoy [this performance of Moon by Origa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeUitrD9CYg) (a Russian-Japanese singer) that contains also the lyrics subtitles (as you may know common in japanese music videos), citing the word *Gablish* in the beggining. The video is from Turn A Gundam live concert.

Yoko Kanno has more such songs:

- *Wo Qui Non Coin* (my favorite from when Cowboy Bebop first aired)
- *Fado*
- *Torukia*
- *Cats on Mars*
- *Green Bird*
- *PAPA Plastic*
- *Dijurido*

In all the above listed songs and probably few more I can't remember, you may think you understand a word or two, but you can't connect them in a sensible context.

In the end it's not that uncommon to invent lyrics by Japanese singers - another quite popular artist that does similar things is [Hitomi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJ7aVGjym9A).

Comment: Are you sure they don't still have a meaning?
A lot of pages list Torukia and its lyrics: e.g. 

https://lyricstranslate.com/de/torukia-%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AD%E3%82%A2-torukia-%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AD%E3%82%A2.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a fair amount of Latin in there.

Translate it through Google Latin translate and it's not all picked up, but a bunch is:

From me and my secret
O fullness, O song
My death sicile ha jus costro
Mawé a little more

E mi et le di fenité

Gladis clang o pledistiant
Being lai viginsé lescayan
Mawe you are a little calf

Taan ma taan la la la la la la loo
Plaute tai mi fai o gunema
(worldwide)
Taan les tai la la la, la la la loo
Die taan mi fai volta

From me and my secret
O fullness, O song
My death sicile ha jus costro
Mawe a little more

Taan ma tai la la la, la la loo
Plaute taan mi fai o gunema
(worldwide)
Tai les tai la la la, la la loo
Die taan mi fai volta

Taan ma tai la la la, la la loo
Plaute taan mi fai o co....
My mo...
Through the...